# My php fetch from an SQL query doesn't return the ID

Tags: php, sql

My Login Function which Returns the Value `$FoundAcc`

```
function Login($Username,$Password){
    global $ConnectingDB;
    $sql = "SELECT admin FROM admin WHERE admin=:admin 
    AND password=:password LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $ConnectingDB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':admin',$Username);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password',$Password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $Result = $stmt->rowcount();
    if ($Result==1){
        return $FoundAcc=$stmt->fetch();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

My PHP login page should save the fetched Row from my DB and save it in a Session Variable (UserID) but It doesn't, It Does however save the (Username)variable from the Row... What is wrong?

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $Username=$_POST["username"];
    $Password=$_POST["password"];
   //if username/password are empty show error//
    if(empty($Username)||empty($Password)){
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "All Fields Must Be Filled Out!";
        Redirect_to("Login.php");
    }else{
        $FoundAcc=Login($Username,$Password);
        // if account and pw found in DB complete following
        if ($FoundAcc){
            //save variables from DB row to session variables
        $_SESSION["UserID"]=$FoundAcc["id"];
        $_SESSION["Username"]=$FoundAcc["admin"];
            //show toast
        $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"] = $_SESSION["UserID"]." Has Successfully Logged In ";
        Redirect_to("Login.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Incorrect Username or Password!";
        Redirect_to("Login.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @Oliver to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: `SELECT admin` should be `SELECT admin, id`.

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords, use instead [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: or use `SELECT *`.

Comment: The account verification is working ok, finding the SQL row isn't the issue I'm pretty sure, or It wouldn't be returning the Username from the SQL row. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sql` query should be like this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin=:admin AND password=:password LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks <3